# "query" count posts for each category expressjs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i am new at MERN stack 
i tried to write this query but i can't and search a lot on google without any solution

## i have to table one for posts and the second for categories

table 1 posts

```
--------------------------
|id   | title  |  category |
--------------------------
| 1   | title1 |    1      |
| 2   | title2 |    2      |
| 3   | title3 |    1      |
| 4   | title4 |    1      |
```

=================
table 2 categories

```
---------------
|id   | name   |
---------------
| 1   |  cat1  |
| 2   |  cat2  |
```

====================
the results i want is this

```
---------------------------------
|id   | name   | number of posts |
---------------------------------
| 1   |  cat1  |        3        |
| 2   |  cat2  |        1        |
```

if it's can a help i write this query in mysql

```
SELECT categories.*,COUNT(posts.id) AS np FROM `categories` JOIN materials ON (categories.id = posts.category) GROUP BY categories.id
```

and thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in mongodb 3.6 and above

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "posts",
    "let": { "id", "$id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$category", "$$id"] }}},
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "as": "count"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "name": 1,
    "numberOfPosts": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$count.count", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Comment: i don't use aggregation i am use the simple code or it can't be done without aggregation ?

Comment: You have posted the sql query which is having a join. Same in mongodb if you want to join two tables you have to use aggregation. And I think there is no other way(except find and then looping)

Comment: this is my code with looping i know sounds crazy but i triad to add the number to the array and not working
app.get("/cats", (req, res) => {
    Cat.find((err, doc) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        doc.forEach(function(u, i) {
            
            Blog.find({"catId" : u._id}).count(function(err, count){
                if(err) return console.log(err);
                console.log(count);
                u["total"] = count;
                console.log(u);
            });
            console.log(u);
            
        })
        res.json(doc);
    })
})

Comment: Sorry @lhbibhbart I cannot help you in that.

Comment: Hello, I have been looking for the same solution and found this really helpful. But wondering if it can be done using default functions like find or something else? I think Aggregate is not that good for large data sets.

Comment: @AnkitShah Please ask a new question I will try to help